# Combining two SQL Queries and their results

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database and I have written one SQL query using joins as below:

```
SELECT
(CT.CRDATTIM || CT.RECORDCD || CT.CRNODE) AS CALLERKEY 
FROM
   W67U999S F 
   JOIN
      W03U999S CT 
      ON F.CCRDATTIM = CT.CRDATTIM 
      AND F.CRECORDCD = CT.RECORDCD 
      AND F.CCRNODE = CT.CRNODE 
      AND F.CRECORDCD = 'T' 
      AND CT.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER' 
   JOIN
      PQCUSTSRV CDT 
      ON F.CCRDATTIM = CDT.CRDATTIM 
      AND F.CRECORDCD = CDT.RECORDCD 
      AND F.CCRNODE = CDT.CRNODE 
WHERE
   F.PCRDATTIM = '2019-01-29-06.10.33.037940' 
   AND F.PRECORDCD = 'F' 
   AND F.PCRNODE = '01' 
   AND CT.CRDATTIM < '9999-12-31-23.59.59.999999'
```

The above query returns me the following rows of data:

```
CALLERKEY
----------
2019-01-29-06.10.33.310940T01
2019-03-26-00.51.05.124040T01
2019-03-26-00.51.07.993040T01
2019-03-26-00.51.35.531040T01
2019-04-02-04.02.42.280040T01
```

Now I want to query for each row using the following SQL query to get some additional data that I am interested in:
Example as below:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS TESTCOUNT FROM PQCUSTSRV where CALLERKEY='2019-01-29-06.10.33.310940T01' AND TO_TIMESTAMP(CRDATTIM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF') 
      BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSTIMESTAMP,-12) AND SYSTIMESTAMP
```

The above query returns the following data:

```
TESTCOUNT
------------
2
```

Now I want to combine the above two queries and get the output as something like below:

```
CALLERKEY                           TESTCOUNT                                               
----------                          --------    
2019-01-29-06.10.33.310940T01       2
2019-03-26-00.51.05.124040T01       3       
2019-03-26-00.51.07.993040T01       2
2019-03-26-00.51.35.531040T01       1
2019-04-02-04.02.42.280040T01       4
```

How can I achieve that? Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with t as (
      <first query here>
     )
select t.callerkey, count(p.callerkey) AS TESTCOUNT
from t left join
     PQCUSTSRV p
     on p.callerkey = t.callerkey and
        to_timestamp(p.CRDATTIM, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF') >= add_months(SYSTIMESTAMP, -12) 
group by t.callerkey;
```

I changed the logic of the date comparison to just use `>=`, assuming that you don't have future values in `crdattim`.

Comment: Sorry ..I am getting the error `ORA-00904: "T"."CALLERKEY": invalid identifier`

Comment: I am curious to know what's wrong in your answer. Could you please correct so that I can learn something new today? +1 for your approach and quick response anyway.

Comment: @Ashok.N . . . I left out the `join`.

Comment: Yep, using right join would fetch me exactly what I want. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` as follows:

```
Select F.CALLERKEY, COUNT(1) AS CNT
  From (your_first_query) f
  Left Join PQCUSTSRV s
    On s.CALLERKEY=f.CALLERKEY AND TO_TIMESTAMP(CRDATTIM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF') 
      BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSTIMESTAMP,-12) AND SYSTIMESTAMP  
 Group by f.callerkey
```

Comment: But somehow the number of  results are wrong. Don't  know what logic in the query causing that.

Comment: I supposed to get five rows as shown in the question, but getting only three. What could be the reason here?

Comment: Ok. You need left join then. See the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but this should work

```
SELECT A.CALLERKEY, COUNT(*) AS TESTCOUNT 
(SELECT (CT.CRDATTIM || CT.RECORDCD || CT.CRNODE) AS CALLERKEY
   FROM W67U999S F
        JOIN W03U999S CT
           ON     F.CCRDATTIM = CT.CRDATTIM
              AND F.CRECORDCD = CT.RECORDCD
              AND F.CCRNODE = CT.CRNODE
              AND F.CRECORDCD = 'T'
              AND CT.WRKTYPE = 'CALLER'
        JOIN PQCUSTSRV CDT
           ON     F.CCRDATTIM = CDT.CRDATTIM
              AND F.CRECORDCD = CDT.RECORDCD
              AND F.CCRNODE = CDT.CRNODE
  WHERE     F.PCRDATTIM = '2019-01-29-06.10.33.037940'
        AND F.PRECORDCD = 'F'
        AND F.PCRNODE = '01'
        AND CT.CRDATTIM < '9999-12-31-23.59.59.999999')A, PQCUSTSRV B
 WHERE A.CALLERKEY=B.CALLERKEY AND TO_TIMESTAMP(CRDATTIM,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF')
      BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSTIMESTAMP,-12) AND SYSTIMESTAMP
 GROUP BY B.CALLERKEY
```